# What does stripped JARs (no bytecode for methods) mean?

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee

I am trying hard to find the [cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553305/where-to-find-and-debug-the-classes-inside-javax-faces-in-jetty) of a weird JSF error. To do this, I try to debug the source code inside javaee-web-api module where a `NullPointerException` is thrown during JSF rendering. But I am stuck because the debugger does not show me the source code of that location.

There is a [discussion thread](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11389) that says that javaee-web-api is stripped (no bytecode for methods) and meant to be used only for compilation.

What does this mean? Can someone explain it in more detail? I want to understand why I cannot debug the location where that NullPointerException is thrown. I think this is related to the fact that these JARs are stripped.

Comment: All I was able to find was this post that documents the same problem, but lists some reasons from Oracle for this happening: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode?_sscc=t

Comment: What does "does not show me the source code of that location" mean? You mean there's no stack trace, or a stack trace with no line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the class files in a jar file will contain information on the line numbers relating to the code in the class - this is called the debug information. A stripped jar simply does not have this information.

You are correct in assuming this is the problem. The stack trace you see won't contain any line numbers relating to the code in the stripped jar. Since the jar is provided by a third-party, there's nothing you can do to get that information.